# Barycentric subdivisions and labeling of $(d-1)$-simplex

Tags: combinatorial-geometry, simplex

I am trying to prove that it is always possible to label the vertices of the $k$-th barycentric subdivision of a $(d −1)$-dimensional simplex with labels
$1, 2, . . . , d$ such that each simplex present obtains all $d$ labels in its
vertices.

For example, in the $2$ dimensional case, the first barycentric subdivision will yield $6$ inscribed triangles.

I am thinking induction on both $k$ and $d$. Any thoughts?

Comment: You're mistaken about the first barycentric subdivision of a 2-simplex: there's also a vertex at the barycenter of the face, and there are 6 triangles in the subdivision. What you've described is a somewhat different process.  Also: have you confirmed your construction is possible for a tetrahedron? (I see it divides into 5 sub-tetrahedra by an analogous process, but can you assign labels to all vertices so that it has the desired property? )

Comment: Ah yes, thank you for your correction. I will modify my post.

Answer (score 0):

As corrected, this is fairly straightforward or impossible, depending on whether you want to have a certain condition satisfied:

- If you want the original vertices to retain their labels (e.g., in a triangle with labels 1, 2, 3 on the vertices, the original vertices, after subdivision, must retain their labels), then it's impossible. Consider the 1D case of a segment with vertex labels 0 and 1: what label will you assign to the midpoint?
- If you're willing to assign fresh labels to every vertex, then the rule is this:

Every vertex of the barycentric subdivision lies in some $p$-face of the original simplex, but no $p-1$-face. In a triangle, for instance, the original vertices lie in a 0-face of the triangle, but no $-1$-face. The midpoints of the edges lie in a 1-face, but in no $0$-face, and so on. (The edge midpoints lie in the $2$-face as well --- the whole triangle -- but since they also lie in a $1$-face, we know that $p$ is not 2.)

Alternatively expressed: aside from the original vertices, every subdivisions vertex $v$ lies in the interior of some $p$-face. For instance, the midpoints of the edges are in the *interior* of the edge, and while they also lie in the triangle, they lie on its *boundary* ... so for these edges, the value of $p$ is $1$. The midpoint of the triangle lies in the middle of the $2$-simplex, so for it, $p = 2$.

Now here's your labelling: Assign the label $0$ to each original vertex, and for each new vertex that lies in the interior of a $p$-face, assign the label $p$.

Now every simplex of the subdivision contains all possible labels. In a triangle, for instance, the triangles of the subdivision each consist of an original vertex, an edge-midpoint, and the face-center, hence have labels 0, 1, 2.

To answer the question you asked: you need to add 1 to each of the values I gave, i.e., assign labels 1, 2, 3 rather than 0, 1, 2.

I don't know precisely how you've defined a simplex (geometrically? Abstractly?) or barycentric subdivision, so I cannot give a proof that this method works, but once you try it on a line-segment, triangle, and tetrahedron, you should be pretty convinced. :)